# Galaxy notes to tex files

Tags: math-mode, msword, word-to-latex, tablet

anyone knows a program that converts notes from Galaxy note 10.1 to .tex files?
I am more concerned about the formulas.
I am also looking for a good program to convert MML to tex language.

Comment: does the note use mathml? if so you can use the pmml2tex xslt to convert to tex

Comment: The S Note app doesn't seem to store the LaTeX source code, but only `png` images of the equations and `xml` files of your original pen input. Have a look at the `snb` files, those are zipped collections of `xml` and image files, but no LaTeX code anywhere...

Comment: Well, I was wondering if there was another app with such function...

Comment: @chessmath: then please edit your question and describe the functionality you need.